# executable file in C

Tags: c, linux, shell, binary, executable

I tried to write a program in C that checks if a certain file is executable or not, if it is a shell script or a binary

`<apue.h>` is a header from the book Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment

I don't think the approach is exactly right (if it's a shell script or binary). I think there is a more efficient solution. Which one do you think?
In addition, what other problems does the code have?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <apue.h>

void checkIfFileExists(const char *fileName);

int main (int argc,char *argv[]) 
{
    char *fileName = argv[1]; 
    if (argc < 2 )
    {
        err_quit("File to check not specified\n");
        return 0;
    }
    if (argc > 2 )
    {
        err_quit("Too many arguments\n");
        return 0;
    }
    checkIfFileExists(fileName);
    return 0;
}

void checkIfFileExists(const char *fileName)
{
    if(!access( fileName, F_OK ))
    {
        if(!access( fileName, X_OK ))
        {
        printf("The file %s is an executable\n",fileName);
        //check if the file is binary or shell script
        }
        else
        {
        printf("The file %s is not an executable\n",fileName);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        err_quit("The file %s was not found\n",fileName);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that for the shell script they mean for you to check the first "line". If the first n bytes are printable ASCII characters, and the first two of those are `#!`, then it can be assumed it is a shell script.

Comment: Similarly for executables, the [ELF format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) has a 4-byte magic value. You could also process more of the header to actually verify it. Perhaps at least read the `e_type` value if you only want to handle executable files. Depends how in-depth you want to go. Have a look at [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question: You can of course check the [magic number](https://go-compression.github.io/reference/magic_numbers/) of a file to make an educated guess of what file it could be, but even if you suspect that the file could be a Unix script, I don't see how you can reliably (i.e without further guessing) say whether it is a **shell** script. For this, you would have to defined the meaning of the word _shell script_. For instance, yould you consider a program written in Tcl as a shell script? What about, say, _Scheme shell_?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stat methods,

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
...

    struct stat myf;
    stat(<file>,&mf);
    
    if( mf.st_mode & S_IXUSR )
          printf("execute");
```

The output is a bitmap from which you can extract the file permission info

look at https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Permission-Bits.html

for the permission define available.